# ASp.NET MVC 1.0 map route to subdirectory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

How to I setup a route of the url `/customer/export/billing` to the controller `Customer.ExportBilling()` ?

When I try this:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "exportCustomerBilling", "customer/export/billing", new { controller = "Customer", action = "ExportBilling" });
```

I get a 404, the controller method is not invoked.

Using `<%= Html.RouteLink("Export customers for billing", "exportCustomerBilling", null) %>` returns the correct link, clicking on it returns a 404.

Comment: what IIS version are you using, and are other routes working correctly?

Comment: running under Cassini, other routes are working.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably got a more general route registered above the Export Billing route.

Drop one of the [Routing Debuggers](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) into your site, and register it in the Global.asax, that will tell you:

1. What order the routes are in.
2. Which route is being matched to your request.

You can usually work out what tweaking you need to perform from there.

Comment: The only other route above this one is routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"); I'll check out the route debugger. Thanks.